# Sailsjs MongoDB Aggregation Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm trying to do an aggregation query to the db for objects with a specific `id`, and sum it all up and as well give me an average.

**My Scenario**

I've a model that looks like this:

```
attributes: {

    user: {
        model: 'user',
        required: true
    },

    rating: {
        type: 'integer',
        enum: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        defaultsTo: 0,
        required: true
    },

    inventory: {
        model: 'subItem'
    },

    size: {
        model: 'size',
        required: true
    },

    isDeleted: {
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultsTo: false
    }
}
```

Aggregating for the average rating like this:

```
const aggQuery = [
    {
        $match: {"size" : theRating.data[0].size, "isDeleted": false}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$size",
            total: { $sum: 1 },
            average: { $avg: "$rating" }
        }
    }
]
```

**My Function**

```
module.exports = {

    aggregateQuery: (model, aggregate) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            model.native(function (err, collection) {
                if (err) return reject(err);

                collection.aggregate(aggregate, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) return reject(err);

                    return resolve(result);
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**Use Case**
I populate the db with 16 records while writing the test, but, after running the aggregate query, I get an empty array

```
NativeQueryService.aggregateQuery(Rating, aggQuery).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The aggregation query looks good. Check for obvious things like collection name, query filter and input values.

Comment: is your 'size' field an ObjectId or an embedded document?

Comment: It's an `ObjectID` @leonziyo

Comment: can you confirm theRating.data[0].size is also an ObjectId and not a document (object)?

Comment: `AggregateCheck:  [ { '$match': { size: '58bc93f08efcbf950019ef1b', isDeleted: false } },
  { '$group': { _id: '$size', total: [Object], average: [Object] } } ]` @leonziyo

Comment: there it is, you are passing a string instead of an ObjectId, it should be ObjectId('58bc93f08efcbf950019ef1b') instead of '58bc93f08efcbf950019ef1b'

Comment: I have no experience with sails.js but you might want to check this out https://jhtechservices.com/using-mongodb-and-sails-js-with-a-basic-one-to-many-association/

Comment: Thanks @leonziyo that was the issue

Comment: I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass a valid `ObjectId` and not a string to your $match stage.

```
{
    $match: {"size" : ObjectId(theRating.data[0].size), "isDeleted": false}
}
```